# How to show CSV data in wiki page?

Tags: wiki

I have an external process that periodically produces a small table (7*10 cells,  expected to grow to 7*20), and saves it in CSV format in a file share. I want to show this table embedded in a Sharepoint wiki page, something like the below mockup. I currently open the csv in Excel and copy-paste it, but I'd like a more automated process.

- How can I do this?

Note: The external process is in my control, and I can make it output the table in a different way. I'd like not to couple it with Sharepoint though.

[image: mockup: table in wiki]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Excel Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms546696.aspx) to publish your csv into SharePoint and will render I believe to the way your like. This should be working for SP 2010 and 2013 at least